# Is the Diamond DA62 pressurized?

Tags: cabin-pressure

In a recent conversation about the Diamond DA62 I was speaking with someone who thought the aircraft was pressurized. I was shocked considering the door design. Shocked to the point of disbelief. A quick Google search referencing the following page seemed to prove that  it was indeed pressurized.

> Yes, the DA62 is pressurized. The aircraft features a baseline cabin pressure altitude of up to 8,000 ft at the specified maximum operating altitude (28,000 ft). This helps to reduce fatigue during long flights, and make the experience of flying more comfortable for passengers.
> https://www.newzealandrabbitclub.net/is-the-da62-pressurized/

Hard to believe! I tried and found no reference to it's differential pressure limits or operation of its pressurization system. There are videos of pilots wearing cannulas above 10,000 feet.

So, is the Diamond DA62 pressurized or not?

Comment: [Diamond's own website](https://www.diamondaircraft.com/en/private-owners/aircraft/da62/tech-specs/) says the DA62's service ceiling is 20,000 ft, which contradicts the New Zealand Rabbit Breeder website you cited... and that makes me somewhat suspicious that the New Zealand Rabbit Club is not the foremost authority on the details of the DA62...

Comment: They also claim that the DA 62 "*is not turbocharged*" but according to the official [fact sheet](https://www.diamondaircraft.com/fileadmin/diamondaircraft/products/austro-engine/AE_E4_Series_Factsheet_01.pdf) (pdf) by Austro Engine, the AE300 are indeed turbocharged. They also say that "*The engines are mounted in the rear of the aircraft’s fuselage and do not use a piston*"... I'd just forget that site...

Comment: It feels to me like the "New Zealand Rabbit Club" page about... aircraft.... is written by AI for the sole purpose of generating clicks in response to Google searches

Comment: There's nothing that inherently prevents those swing-out doors from being used pressurized if the mechanism was beefed up a bit. Compare the doors on the Piper Meridian and all the regional jets and turboprops with integral airstairs, particularly the E145 which doesn't use piano hinges.

Comment: What does the New Zealand Rabbit Club have to do with airplanes?

Comment: I'm 99% sure I know the original source of that quote now. Me: "Is the DA62 pressurized?" ChatGPT: "Yes, the Diamond DA62 is a pressurized aircraft. It is a twin-engine light aircraft manufactured by Diamond Aircraft Industries. The pressurization system allows the cabin to be maintained at a higher atmospheric pressure than the outside environment, providing a comfortable and controlled environment for the occupants during flight. The pressurization system helps to reduce the effects of altitude, such as hypoxia, and allows for more efficient and comfortable high-altitude operations."

Comment: @Someone-OnStrike - I guess that according to the current site policy, I have to tell you not to answer in comments but instead post it as a real answer! (please don't)

Comment: As a Kiwi, I can confirm that website doesn't even know rabbits, let alone airplanes.   Heck - even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_rabbit) knows that the "New Zealand" rabbit breed is from California.  It is clearly a pile of scripted twaddle that doesn't belong on the web.  "do your research" means more than one source, ideally independent sources.

Comment: @Ben this particular page format is a dead giveaway of an AI-generated website intended to harvest views for ads. Search almost any topic now and you'll see at least one or two pages with the exact same layout and very similar writing style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a copy of the Airplane Flight Manual for the [Diamond DA62](http://support.diamond-air.at/fileadmin/uploads/files/after_sales_support/DA62/Airplane_Flight_Manual/Basic_Manual/70125e-r4-complete.pdf) .  I've never seen one (other than an image), but there is no mention of a pressurization system in the Flight Manual.

Image from the [Diamond Aircraft website](https://www.diamondaircraft.com/en/private-owners/aircraft/da62/overview/) :

[image]

Answer (score 16):

No, neither the DA 62 nor the DA-50RG are pressurized, though they do have an integral supplemental oxygen systems onboard.  I have no idea where the New Zealand Rabbit Club(?) came up with that, but they are misinformed.

What appears to be going on is that they are confusing cabin pressurization with critical altitude on the turbos. The DA 62 does have a critical altitude somewhere in the neighborhood of 12 to 14,000 feet MSL and a maximum operating pressure altitude of 20,000 ft.  This is very different than a cabin altitude.  The video also features a Piper PA-46 Meridian, which is, in fact, pressurized, so I don’t know if they are confusing the two aircraft.  In fact, the quoted 8000 foot cabin altitude at FL280 sounds about right for a non-RVSM certificated Meridian.

Comment: Me: "Is the DA62 pressurized?" ChatGPT: "Yes, the Diamond DA62 is a pressurized aircraft. It is a twin-engine light aircraft manufactured by Diamond Aircraft Industries. The pressurization system allows the cabin to be maintained at a higher atmospheric pressure than the outside environment, providing a comfortable and controlled environment for the occupants during flight. The pressurization system helps to reduce the effects of altitude, such as hypoxia, and allows for more efficient and comfortable high-altitude operations."

Comment: AI just ain’t that intelligent, is it?

Comment: Having experience on the DA-42, I would also have concerns on how the 62 would be able to pressurize properly. The doors on it are pretty large and don't really have a good edge seal or a good locking mechanism for pressurization. There is also the little windows on both pilot side windows that pop open pretty easily already with no pressurization.

Comment: @CarloFelicione It's a lot of A, but not much I.